# How to use classes for Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, class

Could you please help me? I use sqlalchemy to reflect tables. In 2 modules I have equal definition of classes GenePanel but different Base classes 
For my first module I have the following:

```
from ..db import Base_of_first_module
from .mixins import TimeStampMixin


class GenePanel(Base_of_first_module, TimeStampMixin):
    __tablename__ = "gene_panel"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "core"}

    panel_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(ForeignKey("core.project.project_id", deferrable=True))
    base_panel_id = Column(ForeignKey("core.gene_panel.gene_panel_id", deferrable=True), index=True)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

For my second module I can write the following and it will work

```
from second_module.db import Base_of_second_module 
from .mixins import TimeStampMixin 
class GenePanel(Base_of_second_module, TimeStampMixin): 
    __tablename__ = "gene_panel" 
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "core"} 
    panel_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    project_id = Column(ForeignKey("core.project.project_id", deferrable=True)) 
    base_panel_id = Column(ForeignKey("core.gene_panel.gene_panel_id", deferrable=True), index=True) title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

I tried to import GenePanel class to my second module. How I can declare correct Base class in my second module?
(to do something like this in my second module `GenePanel.__bases__(Base_of_second_module)`) but it does not work in a proper way.

```
from second_module.db import Base_of_second_module 
from .mixins import TimeStampMixin 
from first_module import Gene_Panel 

GenePanel.__bases__(Base_of_second_module)
```

Comment: can you show the other module and how are you trying to use GenePanel? I don't completely understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to use definition of GenePanel in my second module from my first module. So in other words in my second module I can write the following and it will works

Comment: from second_module.db import Base
from .mixins import TimeStampMixin


class GenePanel(Base, TimeStampMixin):
    __tablename__ = "gene_panel"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "core"}

    panel_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(ForeignKey("core.project.project_id", deferrable=True))
    base_panel_id = Column(ForeignKey("core.gene_panel.gene_panel_id", deferrable=True), index=True)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)

Comment: But I don't want to  write class definition two times. I would like to import its definition from my first module.

Comment: Please, don't put so much code in the comments. Instead, edit your question and add the additional info there. I can't read code like that if I want to keep my eyesight.

Comment: Thank you @spaniard I have corrected my question

Comment: So basically you want to import `GenePanel` from module 1 in module 2, right? For that just use an import statement like `from module_1_filename import GenePanel`. To write the exact import statement I would need the exact project structure.

Comment: Thank you! I did this but i need to redeclare Base class. I can't do that

Comment: So, you need to define  `GenePanel` with 2 different `Base` class? If so, you should try inheritance by creating a parent class which do not inherits from any `Base` class but contains all the common attributes and then implement in each module the class with the corresponding `Base`.

Comment: No problem, write your answer so you can accept it. and upvote my comment if you want to.